# Excel formula related to if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula which satisfy the following condition:
If A1="Yes", then the corresponding cells B1, C1, D1......etc should contain the word "yes"
IfB1="no", then the C1 should be "no" such that the corresponding cell value depends on the previous cell values.

Pls help me out.

Comment: If every cell equals the previous cell, you're describing the trivial case that every cell to the right of A1 contains: =A1.  So this is either a nonsense question or there are other assumptions you haven't explained.  You don't say what else A1 could be if not "Yes", or how B1 gets to be "No".  Would it be "No" because it equals A1?  Is it an input value or a reference to some other result if A1 is not "Yes"?  What you have defined is that every cell to the right of B1 contains =B1.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in B1 cell

```
=IF(A1="YES","YES", "NO")
```

C1 cell

```
=IF(B1="YES","YES", "NO")
```

D1 cell

```
=IF(C1="YES","YES", "NO")
```

and so on...